# gh (GitHub's CLI): the -w flag no longer opens a browser window from WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, github, wsl2

I'm on Windows 10 Pro, I run headless Ubuntu in WSL and in Ubuntu I run this command:

```
gh pr create -w
```

Initially, the `-w` flag used to open a create PR link in the browser on the host OS.

But it no longer does. I have to scroll up, find the link, copy it and paste into the browser. Annoying!

How do I fix it?

Comment: @harrymc The repo you're linking to is irrelevant to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue:

```
gh config set browser wslview
```

Alternatively, this can be added to `.bashrc`:

```
export GH_BROWSER=wslview
```

[Source](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/6938). Credit: [@mislav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11687/mislav).